# Unable to download any pdf packages via composer for larvel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, php-7.0

i am using laravel 5.5 with php 7.0 version, I want to generate a pdf, i tried to install many pdf packages, but unable to install because of php 7.0 version, it requires min 7.1 to install any packages, i tried to find packages for 7.0 verision, but failed.
can anyone help me how to install package for php 7.0 veriosn

Below is the error, that i am getting,

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1 - nwidart/laravel-modules 4.1.0 requires php >=7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only 2 solutions out of this, You either upgrade your PHP version to 7.1 or downgrade your package versions which uses PHP7.0

If you tell me what packages are you using,I could help you out find the packages. Let me know what your use case is exactly, or why your cant upgrade to PHP7.1

Also it is important to note that PHP7.0 includes security vulnerabilities fixed in PHP7.1, So consider upgrading your framework to at-least `Laravel 5.8`

Edit:

here is a package for pdp utilities in laravel 5.5 -> https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf

For laravel5.5 you will have to manually link the packages as auto discovery will not work.

---

Edit 2:

here is the problem, When you use `composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` the composer installs the latest package which is `0.8.4` (compatible with PHP7.1 and higher), What you need to do instead is add the package manually to the composer file and then bind the version `0.8.3` like this under the require object -> `"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.8.3"` and then run `composer update/install` in the terminal

Comment: In my office they are using php 7.0 version, they will not upgrade above 7 version, as they have to pay for it.  &  i am using spatie roles and permission package and  export-import packages, I tried to install the above-mentioned package, its also not working, may i kno is there any inbuilt default pdf generator available in laravel ?

Comment: Not below 5.6, The only solution here is to get compatible packages, give me the link of the packages you are using or having error with, Ill try to make them work in php7.0

Comment: Thank you @goswami, i am trying to install the below packages,    https://packagist.org/packages/dompdf/dompdf#v0.8.3                                  composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Comment: I have edited my answer, Please check if it work. Really appreciate if you could accept/upvote the answer.